# Apple Mach O-Linker Error Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I have used RevMob as an advertising source for awhile now. They just recently came out with reward video ads so I tried to add their new framework. When I dragged the new framework into my Xcode project (which had the same name as the existing framework: RevMobAds.framework) I immediately got an error. I quickly deleted the framework but still have 8 errors on my project that say: Apple Mach O-Linker Error. I have looked up a lot about this and this is what I have tried:

- added $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT) to the Architectures build    active architecture only
- set to 'NO' for 'valid architectures'
- set to arm64, armv7 and armv7s
- deleted the DerivedData folder and its contents, cleaned and built
  again

Here are what my errors look like: *(everything in bold is what is highlighted red for errors)*

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_AVMediaTypeVideo",
referenced from:
      -[RevMobDeviceInfo cameraPermission] in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o)
      ___99-[RevMobFullscreen proceedLoadWithSuccessHandler:andLoadFailHandler:onClickHandler:onCloseHandler:]_block_invoke106
in RevMobAds(RevMobFullscreen.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice",
referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVURLAsset", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RevMobAds(RevMobFullscreen.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLBeaconRegion", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RevMobAds(RevMobBeaconManager.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o)
      objc-class-ref in RevMobAds(RevMobBeaconManager.o)   "_kCLDistanceFilterNone", referenced from:
      -[RevMobDeviceInfo getUserLocation] in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o)   "_kCLLocationAccuracyBest",
referenced from:
      -[RevMobDeviceInfo getUserLocation] in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v
to see invocation)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not going to mess around with the video ads anymore I just want my project to be back the way it was with no errors!  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Also, my valid architectures are listed as armv7, armv7s, and arm64

Comment: Add the AVFoundation and CoreLocation frameworks to your target.

Comment: I searched for so long on the internet trying to figure this out and tried so many different things but that worked! I never thought it would just be that simple! Thank you so much @rmaddy

Comment: Whenever you get a linker error about an unsatisfied symbol, look at the symbol and search for it in the docs. Typically it tells you which framework it's from. For classes, remove the `_OBJC_CLASS_$_` part. For other symbols, just remove the leading underscore.

Comment: Thanks again for your help thats great advice @rmaddy I'll be sure to do that next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same issue before, try adding AVFoundation and CoreLocation frameworks to your project.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if you added CoreLocation to your app, but copied it in instead of doing a relative framework link... so check to make sure you didn't copy CoreLocation.framework into your app by mistake.